# Error with array initialization

Tags: java

New to Java, this is part of a practice question from a question in my book where i'm learning java. I think I've traced the error to the array, in particular to the initialization but i'm not sure how to fix it, why isn this correct?

```
int[][][] arr;

arr= new int[20][][];

arr[0] = new int[1][];
arr[0][0] = new int[10]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1};
```

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson how can i find a post which title is how is this illegal or error with array initialization :/ Well thanks to the two who helped me at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i run it in eclipse it says `Cannot define dimension expressions when an array initializer is provided.`, i think that's really clear for an error message. It means you can either specify the dimensions or the initialize the array. But **NOT** both at the same time.

Change to:

```
inputs[0][0] = new int[]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1};
```

Answer (score 2):

When you supply an array initializer expression, you can't specify the array dimensions too.

You can use :

```
arr[0][0] = new int[]{1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1};
```

Comment: looks like we both came up with the same answer :) op made a change to his post btw

Comment: @JordanGS thanks for letting me know about the edit :)